# Mvc4 display model property in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed one module and it works fine. I have few textboxes and submit button. When submitting textboxes values i will compare those with db values and return result and display. I have used paging also. This is my action method.

```
   [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(int? clientId, DateTime? dateofAction, int? doc_typeid, string employeeID,string citizenId,int? currentFilter, DateTime? filterdateTime,int? filterdocType,string filteredemployeeID,string filteredcitizenId,int? page)
        {
            logDetailsEnumeration model = new logDetailsEnumeration();
            DB_KYC3Entities db = new DB_KYC3Entities();
            var docTypes = from c in db.tm_doc_type select c;
            if (clientId != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                clientId = currentFilter;
            }
            if(dateofAction!=null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                dateofAction = filterdateTime;
            }
            if(doc_typeid != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                doc_typeid = filterdocType;

            }
            if(employeeID!=null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                employeeID = filteredemployeeID;
            }
            if(citizenId!=null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                citizenId = filteredcitizenId;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = clientId;
            ViewBag.filterdateTime = dateofAction;
            int pageSize = 8;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            VerificationLogBAL obj = new VerificationLogBAL();
            int docType = obj.GetDocDetails(doc_typeid?? default(int));
            List<logDetails> logDetails = obj.getlogDetails(clientId?? default(int), dateofAction??DateTime.Now, docType, employeeID, citizenId);
            IPagedList<logDetails> pagedLog = logDetails.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
            model = new logDetailsEnumeration()
            {
                doc_typeid= doc_typeid,
                Count=logDetails.Count,
                employeeID = employeeID,
                citizenId= citizenId,
                logDetails = pagedLog,
                doctype_name=new SelectList(docTypes, "doc_typeid", "doctype_name")
            };
            return View("Index",model);
            }
        }
```

This is View

```
<div class="forms">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "VerificationLog", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="message"></div>

        <div class="loginUsernamePassword">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="dataTable tableHover">
                <tr>
                    <th width="8%" scope="col">Client ID</th>
                    <th width="20%" scope="col">
                        <div class="form-box form-box-default">

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.clientId, ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @id = "clientId", @placeholder = "Client ID", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 20 })

                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th width="10%" scope="col">Date Of Action</th>
                    <th width="20%" scope="col">
                        <div class="form-box form-box-default">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.dateofAction, ViewBag.filterdateTime as string,  new { @id = "dateofAction", @placeholder = "Date Of Action", @class = "txtBox form-control calender validate[required]" })
                            @*@Html.TextBox("dateofAction", ViewBag.filterdateTime as string,  new { @id = "dateofAction", @placeholder = "Date Of Action", @class = "txtBox form-control calender validate[required]" })*@


                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th width="15%" scope="col">Type Of Document</th>
                    <th width="17%" scope="col">
                        <div class="form-box form-box-default">
                            @*@Html.TextBox("typeofDocument", ViewBag.filterdateTime as string, new { @id = "typeofDocument", @placeholder = "Type Of Document", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 20 })*@
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.doc_typeid,Model.doctype_name,"Select",new { @class = "form-control" })

                                                </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th width="15%" scope="col">Employee ID</th>
                    <th width="17%" scope="col">
                        <div class="form-box form-box-default">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.employeeID, Model.employeeID, new { @id = "employeeID", @placeholder = "Employee ID", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 20 })

                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th width="15%" scope="col">Citizen ID</th>
                    <th width="17%" scope="col">
                        <div class="form-box form-box-default">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.citizenId, Model.citizenId, new { @id = "citizenId", @placeholder = "Citizen ID", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 20 })


                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th width="10%" scope="col" colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons search" />
                </tr>
            </table>

            </div>
            }

        </div>

        @if (Model != null && Model.logDetails.Count != 0)
        {
            <br />
            <h2>Verification Log</h2>
            <br />
            <div id="GridDetails">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="dataTable tableHover">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Label</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                        <th>UpdatedOn</th>
                        <th>UpdatedBy</th>
                        <th>UpdatedStatus</th>
                        <th>RejectComment</th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var group in Model.logDetails)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@group.contentLabel</td>
                            <td>@group.contentValue</td>
                            <td>@group.updatedOn</td>
                            <td>@group.updatedBy</td>
                            <td>@group.updatedStatus</td>
                            <td>@group.rejectComment</td>
                        </tr>

                    }
                </table>

                @Html.PagedListPager(Model.logDetails, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, filterdateTime=ViewBag.filterdateTime, filterdocType= Model.doc_typeid, filteredemployeeID = Model.employeeID, filteredcitizenId = Model.citizenId }))
                Page @(Model.logDetails.PageCount < Model.logDetails.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.logDetails.PageNumber) of @Model.logDetails.PageCount
            </div>
        }
```

Above code works fine. I have some difficulties. Inside action method i have model. Inside model i have  Count=logDetails.Count. Count will be holding number of rows returned. When the first time page loads the count value will be 0 and when there is no corresponding matching data in database then also count value will be 0. I want to display message something like below.

```
var records = @Html.Raw(Model.Count);
             if(records==0)
             {
                 fun_toastr_notify('success','No Records Found');
             }
```

It also works but it also pops up message when the page loads first time(count will be zero). May i know how can I avoid this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use Viewbag or Viewdata and set  count value to it. If viewbag is null then it is first request. When it comes from your action set it to count number and then you can make a comparison there.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like that? (that code has been written on the fly, not tested)

```
<script type="javascript/text">
         document.ready(function(){
            @if (Model.logDetails.Count != 0)
            {
                fun_toastr_notify('success','No Records Found');
            }
         };
</script>
```

Comment: Model.logDetails.Count will be zero when page loads first time and when there is no correspond data in db that time also Model.logDetails.Count will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

for the first time pass a viewbag.isfirsttime = true depending on search parameters or whatever you have to differentiate if it is first time.
than in code

```
<script>

    @{
        var count = !ViewBag.IsFirstTime ? Model.Count : -1;
     };
    var records = @count;
    if (records == 0) {
        fun_toastr_notify('success', 'No Records Found');
    }
</script>
```

This will work surely. Happy Coding !

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole how are you using it ? share the code please

Comment: Thank you. Same as you posted above.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole but how are you adding viewbag in controller ?